# To speed up hive process, how to adjust mapper and reducer number using tez

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

I tried the process(word labeling of sentence) of large data(about 150GB) using tez , but the problem is that it took so much time(1week or more),then

I tried to specify number of mapper.
Though I set mapred.map.tasks =2000,
but I can't stop mapper being set to about 150,
so I can't do what I want to do.

I specify the map value in oozie workflow file and use the tez.

How can I specify the number of mapper?

Finally I want to speed up the process, it is ok not to use tez.

In addition, I would like to count labeled sentence by reducer, it takes so much time,too.

And , I also want to know how I adjust memory size to use each mapper and reducer process.

Comment: `mapred.map.tasks` doesn't do anything for Tez because it's not MR Hive engine being ran. Plus, that property is deprecated

Comment: See  this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842117/2700344

Answer (score 1):

> In order to manually set the number of mappers in a Hive query when TEZ is the execution engine the configuration `tez.grouping.split-count` can be used...
>
> ... `set tez.grouping.split-count=4` will create 4 mappers

https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/How-to-manually-set-the-number-of-mappers-in-a-TEZ-Hive-job

---

However, overall, you should optimize the storage format and the Hive partitions before you even begin [**tuning the Tez settings**](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/14309/demystify-tez-tuning-step-by-step.html). Do not try and process data `STORED AS TEXT` in Hive. Convert it to ORC or Parquet first.

If Tez isn't working out for you, you can always try Spark. Plus labelling sentences is probably a Spark MLlib worlflow you can find somewhere

Comment: Do you know how to adjust number of reducer and 
allocated memory size of it?

Comment: `mapreduce.job.reduces`, and same memory settings that control the mapper container should control the reducer