# Performance issues of small files on Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hadoop2, apache-tez

I was reading an article regarding how small files degrade the performance of the hive query. 
https://community.hitachivantara.com/community/products-and-solutions/pentaho/blog/2017/11/07/working-with-small-files-in-hadoop-part-1

I understand the first part regarding overloading the NameNode.

However, what he had said regrading **map-reduce** doesn't seem to happen. for both **map-reduce** and **Tez**.

> When a MapReduce job launches, it schedules one map task per block of
>   data being processed

I don't see mapper task created per file.May the reason is, he is referring the **version 1 of map-reduce** and so much change haver been done after that.

**Hive Version:** Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.4.0-91

**My table**:

```
create table temp.emp_orc_small_files (id int, name string, salary int)
stored as orcfile;
```

**Data:**
following code will create 100 small files it containing only few kb of data.

```
 for i in {1..100}; do hive -e "insert into temp.emp_orc_small_files values(${i}, 'test_${i}', `shuf -i 1000-5000 -n 1`);";done
```

However I see only **one mapper** and **one reducer** task being created for following query.

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# hive -e "select max(salary) from temp.emp_orc_small_files"
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.6.4.0-91/0/hive-log4j.properties
Query ID = root_20180911200039_9e1361cb-0a5d-45a3-9c98-4aead46905ac
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1536258296893_0257)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 ..........   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 ......   SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 02/02  [==========================>>] 100%  ELAPSED TIME: 7.36 s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK
4989
Time taken: 13.643 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Same result with map-reduce.

```
hive> set hive.execution.engine=mr;
hive> select max(salary) from temp.emp_orc_small_files;
Query ID = root_20180911200545_c4f63cc6-0ab8-4bed-80fe-b4cb545018f2
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1536258296893_0259, Tracking URL = http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8088/proxy/application_1536258296893_0259/
Kill Command = /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1536258296893_0259
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2018-09-11 20:05:57,213 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2018-09-11 20:06:04,727 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.37 sec
2018-09-11 20:06:12,189 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 7.36 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 7 seconds 360 msec
Ended Job = job_1536258296893_0259
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 7.36 sec   HDFS Read: 66478 HDFS Write: 5 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 7 seconds 360 msec
OK
4989
```

Comment: If you use ACID tables w/ ORC + Hive Streaming, then it'll compact the small files

Comment: this are normal ORC tables, without partitioning or bucketing. And I can see 100 files created after the insert statement.

Comment: The number of files isn't really important, more the size of them... Might want to see https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/using-hive-acid-transactions-to-insert-update-and-delete-data/ Other than that, Tez needs to have a warm-up period, and running the same query multiple times in a row on the same table can yield different results

Comment: @cricket_007 the link you posted explains about transctional table, and this is not.

Comment: I am just trying to understand why it isn't if you are going to complain about the performance difference of the small files, that is all

Comment: I am trying to understand if that statement `1 mapper task per block` is true in newer version of hive with either TEZ or MR.  as I don't see it. I have 100 files (385 B) occupying one block each.

Comment: Hive will internally use a `CombineFileInputFormat`, like that link you have mentions (see parts 2 and 3) for dealing with small files. See `hive.tez.input.format` or `hive.input.format` properties

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks `hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat` now I understand what is happening. So small files is not that big an issue if the numbers are not huge.

Comment: Please read also this answer about the number of mappers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842117/2700344

Answer (score 0):

This is because the following configuration is taking effect

```
hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat
```

from the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat)

> Whether to combine small input files so that fewer mappers are
>   spawned.

So essentially Hive can infer that the input is a group of small files smaller than the blocksize and combine them reducing the required number of mappers.

Comment: I have set that as false, `hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat=false`

Comment: same behavior setting it to false?

Comment: it's set a false only.